# Kivy unit testing with Recorder module

Tags: python, unit-testing, kivy

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my Kivy application, and it seems like a good approach is to use the recorder module to perform some simple actions and then assert that the appropriate widgets are added/destroyed (or, since I'm using the Storage module, that the DictStore is updated).

I was successful in making a recording, but I can't figure out how to run my app and playback the recording.  I've done quite a bit of google-ing, but I can't seem to find an example.  Here's what I have so far:

```
from my_app import MyApp
from kivy.input.recorder import Recorder

def recorder_loop(instance, value):
    if value is False:
        instance.play = True

app = MyApp()
app.run()
rec = Recorder(filename='my_recorded_file.kvi')
rec.bind(play=recorder_loop)
rec.play = True
app.stop()
```

But, I'm confused here.  Once I call `app.run()`, it seems like python then waits for input from the application rather than executing the recorder code.  So, how can I play back this recording?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it waits. An application is just an infinite loop with executing some code over and over. If there wasn't input handled, you wouldnt be even able to interact with it. Imagine it like `while True: pass`.

An application however works a little bit different and it gives you an option to interact from outside, if you are able to "pause" the infinite loop, so that it can fetch whatever you like to do with it.

Although `Recorder` is quite nice module, it's superslow for testing even after editing the time between actions, therefore using it has to have a really good reason, otherwise it's just wasting resources and *time*, which are precious while testing.

Read my ["article"](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyUnitTest) about unittesting with Kivy, there's even a package that runs multiple tests (something like nose, but way simpler). I'm not really planing to remove that repo, but in case something happened:

```
import unittest

import os
import sys
import time
import os.path as op
from functools import partial
from kivy.clock import Clock

main_path = op.dirname(op.dirname(op.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(main_path)

from main import My


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    # sleep function that catches `dt` from Clock
    def pause(*args):
        time.sleep(0.000001)

    # main test function
    def run_test(self, app, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.pause, 0.000001)

        # Do something
        app.my_button.dispatch('on_release')
        self.assertEqual('Hello Test', app.my_button.text)
        #self.assertEqual('Fail Test', app.my_button.text)

        # Comment out if you are editing the test, it'll leave the
        # Window opened.
        app.stop()

    # same named function as the filename(!)
    def test_example(self):
        app = My()
        p = partial(self.run_test, app)
        Clock.schedule_once(p, 0.000001)
        app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The method "pause" pauses the App's infinite loop from inside in intervals and allows you to interact with it quite easy.

Let's get into the less pleasant part. When testing, you'll probably need to navigate into some widgets and so on, but there's an urge when using this way to put everything into App class to be easily accessible. Don't do that, you'll run out of names really quickly and it'll make your main code more confusing.

Although `something.ids.<id>.children[1].ids. ...` isn't nice to see, it's handy, because it lets you see how deep you probe a tree, where are you and... you can still put it into a variable in the beginning of a test. When making a test, it's handy to look at `kv` file, it makes traversing children trees easier to write.

Feel free to check [my tests](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KrySA/tree/master/krysa/tests).

---

Update: Recently I've seen something new-ish from Tito, which will definitely help with better object accessing than via `ids` - [*Telenium*](https://github.com/tito/telenium).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips, and links to other unit tests.  I've managed to start writing a few tests for my app now!